# Sending SMS from one SIM to another SIM in dual SIM mobile

Tags: android

Is it possible to send sms from one SIM to second SIM in dual SIM mobiles using SmsManager..??
Any idea or link would be helpful that I can use to learn about these things..I am new to android..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Want to send a SMS to a phone number.Its Doesn't a Problem you are sending to your own mobile or another sim.

This [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm) will help with the sample

Comment: yeah sure..but let me check it first.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send sms to another sim in the same phone. When you are sending an sms it will be send to the number specified and there is no role for dual sim or same sim . You can send sms from your number to your number also.